# How can I add audio and video with selectable tracks to a Jekyll personal blog?

Tags: plugins, jekyll, blogs

Is there a plugin that allows for cross-page music and video playback within Github Pages

The content I found seems to suggest that playback can only be achieved by referencing third-party links.

I just started using Jekyll for building websites and have seen many answers to this type of question, but they are all about adding music to a single page itself.